# iPhone app submission Checklist. Why no mention of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities?

Tags: iphone, submission

I've been looking at various posts of iPhone app submission checklists, to prep for submission to Apple, but they are either not thorough enough or maybe I'm missing something (or not finding the right checklists).

For example UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities seems pretty important, but it doesn't get mentioned much anywhere. Is this kind of thing considered too obvious? What other obvious things should I know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because it seems more like a part of the design or development process, deciding what is required - at time of submission you should have that all hammered out and setting those values is more a part of testing than final deployment.

Comment: Except that these things aren't needed for design and development. I have a working app, works on Simulator, works on iPhone 4 actual device. I haven't set anything for UIRequriedDeviceCapabilities. So its obviously not required, it seems totally specific to the app store selling process. I'd love to have a list of the other absolutely crucial items like this. Anybody?

Comment: It's not required for functionality, but it is a really, really good idea for testing to try putting it on a device it's not supposed to be able to support to make sure it's locked down OK!  That's why I say that the supported device limitations are things generally thought about, and tested, before you are ready to submit to the app store.

Comment: @Paul - I agree with Kendall on this.  Few people use this key, and for those that do they typically implement it during the development process, when they realize that a particular piece of hardware is necessary for the application to even run.  For a list of all supported keys, see Apple's documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Answer (score 0):

I think some of that is more conditional in nature, meaning a lot of times people don't need to use that particular key unless they want to restrict access to their app based on what device the user has.

This is the one I always went by in the past:  http://developer.apple.com/news/ios/appstoretips/

But honestly, the most important ones are:

1. Make sure all the app meta data is filled out and you aren't using any trademarks/copyrighted items anywhere in your app
2. Make sure you checked your app for memory leaks and fixed bugs for crashing
3. Don't use other app names in your keywords
4. Make sure you have error messages
   for network issues (or anything else
   that might make a button appear like
   it does nothing and would confuse
   the user)

Comment: My understanding is that if you say use GPS but don't put it in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, then Apple will reject it.

Comment: That is probably correct since Apple doesn't want users to download an app that needs GPS when their device doesn't support it.  That falls under the make the app "..appear like it does nothing and would confuse the user" category :)  If you follow that guideline, you'll probably be okay.  However, nothing is 100% guaranteed with Apple's bi-polar app review process.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:

"Here are some of the important keys that you might want to add to your application’s Info.plist file specifically for iOS:" (according to iOS programming guide). But from what I can tell only CFBundleIconFiles, and UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities are really required (unless you have no required capabilities in which case leave that one out I guess).

```
  CFBundleIconFiles
*

  UIStatusBarStyle
*

  UIInterfaceOrientation
*

  UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
*

  UIRequiresPersistentWiFi
```